# JQuery Colorbox: Resize very large image to given size

Tags: jquery, css, html, image, colorbox

How to resize very large image to the given settings , for example the image is 2660x2000 something, then how to resize it to 1024x960? I tried all the possible help, but cant get what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Just write in your css:

```
(img selector) {
   max-width: 1024px;
   height: auto; /*Height is auto the image to be re-sized proportionally */
}
```